# How can I properly initialize my Android emulator using AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to run an Android emulator from command-line because I couldn't run it from Android Studio (it gave the same problem plus some error messages such as "Time out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online" and "The emulator process for AVD was terminated").

When I run

```sh
emulator -avd flutter_emulator -no-snapshot-load -debug-init -logcat '*:v'
```

it shows a black emulator screen followed by some output in the terminal, ending with

```
VERBOSE | registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '196608'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.adb.secure' = '1'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '512m'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '420'
INFO    | Rootcanal has  been activated.
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-dpad: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-trackball: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-camera: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-keyboard: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: true
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-tabletmode: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-touch: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-multitouch: false
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'net.wifi_mac_prefix' = '5554'
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.apic [bit 9]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:EDX [bit 9]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm [bit 5]
VERBOSE | Not using any http proxy
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
VERBOSE | android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_9223.ini
```

When I press the power button on emulator, the following contents are appended to the terminal:

```
INFO    | Critical: Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/mapsjs/gen_204?csp_test=true: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'qrc://' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'qrc://' is therefore not allowed access. (qrc:/html/js/common.js:0, (null))

INFO    | Critical: Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/mapsjs/gen_204?csp_test=true: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'qrc://' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'qrc://' is therefore not allowed access. (qrc:/html/js/common.js:0, (null))
```

After that, the emulator gets stuck with a black screen (at least I've waited for about an hour). How can I initialize it properly?
Alternatively, can I change the source code anywhere to avoid connecting with the Google Maps API, if that's the problem?

What I've tried:

- changing the `hw.ramSize` value on *config.ini* to values up to 2048MB
- setting `hw.gpu.enabled` to "yes" and `hw.gpu.mode` to "host"
- setting `hw.gps` to "no" (since the critical message refers to a  Maps API)

The emulator gets stuck with [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcJZD.png).

---

**Outputs**:

- `inxi -F`:

```
System:    Host: computador Kernel: 4.15.0-167-generic x86_64 bits: 64
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.8.9  Distro: Linux Mint 19 Tara
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: INTEL model: HM65DESK serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: 4.6.5 date: 02/23/2019
CPU:       Single core Intel Core i7-2640M (-UP-) cache: 4096 KB
           speed/max: 1596/3500 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel 2nd Generation Core Integrated Graphics Controller
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 3000 (SNB GT2)
           version: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Def. Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Microsoft LifeCam VX-800 driver: USB Audio
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-167-generic
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full
           mac: 0a:e0:af:b8:14:25
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 3060.6GB (8.0% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: SATA_SSD size: 60.0GB
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: ST3000NM0053 size: 3000.6GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 55G used: 45G (86%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 100.0C mobo: 27.8C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 211 Uptime: 1:57 Memory: 3398.1/15929.4MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

- `emulator --version`

```
Android emulator version 31.2.7.0 (build_id 8135630) (CL:N/A)
```

- `emulator -accel-check`:

```
accel:
0
KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
accel
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I was starting mine with the below as I was trying to push a new hosts file:

```
-writable-system
```

And had just performed:

```
adb remount
adb reboot
```

The critical warning about maps proved to be a red herring.  My emulator would only reboot to a black screen.  I finally ran the command like this and it came back:

```
.\emulator -avd Pixel_5_API_30 -gpu host -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

I'm running my emulator on Windows 11 with Hyper-V acceleration enabled.